# php clear server cache for image

Tags: php, caching, server

I have a php script which copies an image to a folder every hour over writing the last image, the name of the image is always the same, image.jpg , im using ifttt to post the image to a website but the image posted is always the same image even though I have checked to see the image is different. so it must be posting the image from the cache? I added clearstatcache(); to the code but it doesn't work. is there any other way of clearing the cache so the actual image is posted? the image is hosted on a shared server. Thanks

```
$from = '/A1';
$files = scandir($from);

$to = '/A2';
if (!empty($files[2])) {
rename("{$from}/{$files[2]}", "{$to}/image.jpg");
}
clearstatcache();
```

Comment: please add you PHP code to question

Comment: you have too many unaccepted questions.

Comment: @Zoha I have edited the question and entered the code. thanks

Comment: @gp_sflover what are unaccepted questions and where do I find them? thanks

Comment: Obviously it was a mistake and I've to correct myself. You never accepted any answer on 20 questions o-O

Comment: OK doing it now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved with .htaccess file

```
 <FilesMatch "\.(css|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|mp3|mp4|png|pdf|swf|txt)$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Pragma
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header unset Last-Modified
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
 </FilesMatch>
```

Thanks for all your help!